# Seems 2FA login authentication is trivial to bypass on Ubuntu. What am I missing?

Tags: login, password, security, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I was considering setting up 2FA on Ubuntu with *libpam-google-authenticator* as outlined [in this article](https://www.tecmint.com/enable-two-factor-authentication-in-ubuntu/). However, it seems this method can be completely bypassed by entering GRUB rescue mode and removing the *.google-authenticator* file in the home directory.

```
# rm /home/username/.google_authenticator
```

Then comment out the following line in */etc/pam.d/common-auth* file

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Am I overlooking anything? **How could you allow the ability to disable 2FA without having to provide any type of 2FA code?** It seems to defeat the purpose of enabling 2FA in the first place.

Comment: There is a well-known rule of security, "if you have physical access to the machine, you can do anything". If you want your machine to be secure, you must take care of physical security first. Even if GRUB rescue mode required 2FA, you could always boot from live media and do the same as you described. And it is actually good. These things are last resort to recover when you screw up your system.

Comment: If this scenario concerns you, encrypt your hard drive.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - even if I encrypt my hard drive the config file has to remain outside the encrypted partition, to allow the login process access to the config file prior to decryption. Therefore I don't think full disk encryption is the solution? It seems this _Authenticator PAM module_ only offers the illusion of security. Am I right? _Source:_ [https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019